# Nibble Hex from Java to PHP

Tags: java, php, hex

I'm translating one app from java to php and i'm finding some trouble.

I have a string like this `98191107990D0000EF050000789C65970BCCD75318C7CFEFFC` ... in java there's this function where I pass this string as parameter:

```
private static byte[] decodeNibbleHex(String input)
  {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length - 1; i += 2) {
      char[] bChars = new char[2];
      bChars[0] = chars[i];
      bChars[1] = chars[(i + 1)];
      int val = Integer.decode("0x" + new String(bChars)).intValue();
      baos.write((byte)val);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
  }
```

but... i don't know to to translate this function in PHP... i tried too many times and i'm becoming crazy! i tried with a for cycle, with this `eval("\$hex = 0x" . $dati[$i].$dati[$i+1] . ";");` and this `$binary_string = pack("h*" , $dati[$i].$dati[$i+1]);` and many many other functions...

If someone understand Java and can help me I will appreciate it!!

Thank guys!

Comment: Can we see one of your tries? Maybe it's really close and needs a small tweak.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.hexdec.php#100578

Is this not exactly what you whrere looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct of your java function, it takes the string's chars in pairs, and threats them as bytes and put them in a ByteArray. In php there's no such thing as a byte array but you can represent random binary data in everyday strings. This is my take on your function (didn't tried to compare with the java code's output).

```
$str= '98191107990D0000EF050000789C65970BCCD75318C7CFEFFC';

$output[] = array();
for ($i=0, $c = strlen($str) - 1; $i < $c; $i+=2) {
    $output[] = chr(intval($str[$i].$str[$i+1], 16));
}

print join($output); // binary string, not really useful in ascii terminal (-:
```

In summary this seem to be a `base16_decode()` function, with `base16_encode()` written like it follows, you get back the input string:

```
function base16_encode($str) {
    $byteArray = str_split($str);
    foreach ($byteArray as &$byte) {
        $byte = sprintf('%02x', ord($byte));
    }   
    return join($byteArray);
}
print base16_encode(join($output)); // should print back the original input.
```